# Show certain rows of a table based on the id value and toggle through all values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a table which has rows grouped in fives with matching id's which are: one, two, three, four, etc.

I need to only show each the rows with the id one with a next button followed by two with a next button and so on and so forth until I have reached the end of the table and then show a submit button for the form that is enclosed within the table.

I'm a complete javascript novice which is why when I try to use the jquery toggle function I'm getting nowhere! I'd really appreciate it if someone could at least point me in the direction of a tutorial which has the toggle function on multiple rows in a table.

Cheers!

EDIT: after some confusion and reading though the question again I realise I'm not being clear on the fact that I just want some pointers on the correct functions to use within jquery. and if I am in the right ball park. I'm not looking for the code to be completely writen for me. Sorry If I came across as that.

Comment: Show us what you tried that didn't work.

Comment: All ids should be unique, ie no two elements should have the same id. http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H93 and http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-WCAG20-20081211/#ensure-compat-parses

Comment: @Madbreaks I got lost trying it out I don't really know where to start with javascript at all.

Comment: @mrk I am aware of the id w3 rules it would work the same as classes however something else I read while looking about suggested a method using the ID of the table row.

Comment: If you put together a jsfiddle, or at the very least post some code, I'd be happy to help.  There's probably no easy-to-find tutorial doing exactly what you want, but it sounds pretty simple.  I just don't want to have to write it all from scratch

Comment: Then I'd suggest running through some JS tutorials.  No offense intended, but this site isn't a code-writing service - you'll want to try some things, and post back here if you can't figure it out, with the code that you tried that didn't work.

Comment: @ZachL cheers, I've put the html that is created by my PHP code in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/longsden/xwVf5/

Comment: Post some code, i can write it myself, but the object is for you to learn how to write it yourself

Comment: ...theres no javascript in that jsfiddle

Comment: I appreciate that @Madbreaks I don't expect it handed to me on a plate! Just some pointers of where I need to be looking. If someone can help me with that I'll work it out. Sometimes you just need a nudge in the right direction!

Comment: eep, looks like your code is stuck in 2005 - you shouldn't be using tables at all from the looks of it, and certainly not `<center>`

Comment: @ZachL yeah the center is horrible. It's a schnide fix while i get sent over the design it's a table at the moment so i don't have to worry about css as well. if I'd realised I'd need to be showing off the code earlier I would have done some tidying up. I just wanted to show you what basic code there is at the moment

Comment: @Longsden—don't post code on some other site. Create a minimal example and post it here so it, and the answers it spawns, can be of use to others.

Comment: Cheers @RobG I've got a couple of idea's now where I need to go with this. Once I have a solution for what I want to do I will post it here.

Answer (score 0):

If you need help learning jquery toggle specifically you should really just look up the [Jquery Documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/toggle)

As you are probably noticing in the comments above, StackOverflow isn't a site where you get code handed to you -- you have to code yourself and we can give you advice/tips for nit picky fixes, syntax, confusing concepts, or different approaches to a problem.

Here was a really good tutorial I used when I first learned [Jquery at Codeschool](http://www.codeschool.com/courses/jquery-air-first-flight) so take a look at that. It's really interactive and you really do learn fast. I also believe it will teach you some basic of basics of Javascript.

[W3schools](http://w3schools.com/js/default.asp) is also very good for learning JS or web development in general so you might want to hang around there.

When you post some more code, I can edit my answer to better help you with your problem. You wanted some nice tutorials dealing with tables and while I could probably find a JS tutorial specifically dealing with tables, that's not how you should be learning. I'll try to find a tutorial that suits your needs but you should learn from the ground up and work your way through. That's how I did it, and many of us have done it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Cheers, it's about time I learnt what the hell the little bits of jquery & javascript are doing. I've just found a code example that seems quite helpfull I'll try and modify it and let you know what I come up with!

Answer (score 0):

You can use something fairly generic that just toggles tbody elements. Adapt the following as necessary, it doesn't need any ids.

I've grouped the rows to show and hide in tbody elements for ease of dealing with them.

```
<script>

var toggleRows = (function() {
    var hidden = -1;

    return function(el) {
      var tbodies;

      // Get the table from the passed element
      // The element must be in the table, or be the table
      while (el.tagName.toLowerCase() != 'table') {
        el = el.parentNode;
      }

      // Get just tbody elements, exclude thead and tfoot
      tbodies = el.tBodies;

      // Hide them all
      for (var i=0, iLen=tbodies.length; i<iLen; i++) {
        tbodies[i].style.display = 'none';
      }

      // Show the next tbody, or first if were showing the last one
      tbodies[++hidden % iLen].style.display = '';
    }

}());

window.onload = function() {
  toggleRows(document.getElementById('section1'));
}
</script>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3"><span onclick="toggleRows(this);">Show next</span></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="section1">
    <tr>
      <td>foo 1<td>bar 1<td>fum 1
  <tbody id="section2">
    <tr>
      <td>foo 2<td>bar 2<td>fum 2
  <tbody id="section3">
    <tr>
      <td>foo 3<td>bar 3<td>fum 3
</table>
```

Comment: oohhh, a no-jquery solution!

Comment: Yeah, hugely dangerous. If the OP doesn't know javascript, s/he shouldn't be bothering with jQuery.